# PHP search multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

**Table: tblBuilding**
**buildingid..........  buildingname................    buildinglocation**

1.........  ................Clinic...............................   Alice Road
2.........  ................    Winter Mall.....................    Damansara
3.........  ................    Faculty...........................  Beijing Road
4.........  ................    Star Mall.........................  Pavillion

**Table: tblperson**
**personid.......personname..................   personno..........**    **personbuilding**

1   ....................Dr Andrew Clarkson......    0312883232.......   Clinic
2   ....................Mr Antoine......................    0825112315.......   Winter Mall
3   ....................Mrs Emmy Dahliana.......    0112357125.......   Faculty
4....................   Prof Justin Andrew......... 0524128866.......   Faculty
5....................   Dr Sanila .......................   0225113070........  Clinic

If I enter the keyword as **Andrew**, my expected result is 
id:1
personname: Dr Andrew Clarkson
personno: 0312883232
personbuilding: Clinic
buildinglocation: Alice Road

If I enter the keyword as **Star Mall**, my expected result is
buildingid: 4
buildingname: Star Mall
buildinglocation: Pavillion

My code:

```
if (isset($_GET["FirstName"])) 
{
    $FirstName = $_GET['FirstName'];
}

$query= "(SELECT * FROM tblBuilding where buildingname like '%".$FirstName."%' OR buildinglocation '%".$FirstName."%') UNION (SELECT * FROM tblperson where personname like '%".$FirstName."%' OR personno '%".$FirstName."%' or personbuilding (SELECT * FROM tblBuilding where buildingname like '%".$FirstName."%' OR buildinglocation '%".$FirstName."%')) "

mysql_query($query);
```

This query return empty result. The error is shown as below.

```
   Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbinfo\getDetails.php on line 68 {"success":0,"message":"Keyword(s) not found"}
```

Comment: The query returns nothing because it generates a syntax error.  You should (1) include the error in your question.  (2) Explain what you are trying to do.  (3) Include sample data and desired results.  SQL code that doesn't work does a poor job of explaining what one is trying to do.

Comment: You cannot Union two tables with different schema.

Comment: Also, the two tables have different number of columns. So, the query should be changed to select only a few columns (those which match the schema of the columns of first table) from the second table if you wish to use union.

Comment: i tried the query by using inner join. 
SELECT * FROM tblbuilding INNER JOIN tblperson ON tblbuilding.buildingname = tblperson.personbuilding 
    WHERE tblbuilding.BuildingName like '%".$FirstName."%'  .
The produced result was not the one that i wanted.

Comment: may i know is there any solution for this? Or I have to look for other solution as the schema of the tables are different , so UNION is not applicable for it.

Comment: Hmm.... i tink i found the solution. I used if...else statement. Means that, my php file consists of two queries, if the first query get 0 row, then i execute the second query else return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION operator works with same column name. You should alias column names of both tables with same name. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think now it's fixed . give a try :)  NB: Notice that each SELECT statement  within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

```
if (isset($_GET["FirstName"])) 
{
$FirstName = $_GET['FirstName'];
}

$query= "(SELECT * FROM tblBuilding where buildingname like '%".$FirstName."%' OR buildinglocation LIKE '%".$FirstName."%' ) UNION (SELECT * FROM tblperson where personname LIKE '%". $FirstName ."%' OR personno '%".$FirstName."%' or personbuilding (SELECT * FROM tblBuilding where buildingname LIKE '%".$FirstName."%' OR buildinglocation '%".$FirstName."%')) ";

 mysql_query($query);
```